# How to access and mutate private field in scala?

Tags: scala

I have something like:

```
class Address(private var street:String, private var city: String, private var postCode: String) extends Model
```

When I try to do:

```
address = new Address(....)
address.city = "changed"
```

I get compile error.
So what is the solution? Note that the fields must remain private.

Also is there a shortcut syntax than having to repeat the keyword private when all fields in the class are private?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding here. All fields in Scala are private. It's not just a default nor is it optional.

For example, let's say you have this:

```
class Address(var street: String)
```

The field where `street` is stored is *private*. Say you do this:

```
val x = new Address("Downing")
println(x.street)
```

This code does not directly access the private field for `street`. `x.street` is a *getter method*.

Say you do this:

```
x.street = "Boulevard"
```

This code does not directly modify the private field for `street`. `x.street =` is actually the method `x.street_=`, which is a *setter method*.

You can't directly access fields in Scala. Everything is done through getters and setters. In Scala, every field is private, every field has getters, and every `var` has setters.

Comment: The tone of this answer seems almost... angry?

Comment: I wouldn't call it angry. Thanks for explaining the concepts @Danial

Comment: Not angry, emphatic. I'm being overly emphatic because I know that point was made before. I'm trying to be sure the point is made here.

Comment: The reason Scala takes this approach (the uniform access principle, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) is to facilitate changing implementation details--the user of an interface shouldn't care whether he's accessing a stored field or a method. Making everything a method call should help with binary compatibility. However, an exception to the rule "in Scala, all is done through getters and setters" is access to classes defined in Java, right?

Comment: ... another reason to make every "field access" a method call is that this allows overriding of behavior.

Comment: @Kipton Yes, fields in Java can be accessed from Scala as if through getters and setters. In fact, it would be more precise to say that there's no distinction between a field and a getter/setter in Scala, because of Uniform Access Principle. I make the distinction here for both reasons of implementation in the JVM (and access from Java) and to make it clear that the Java pattern of private field/public getter/public setter is utterly unnecessary.

Comment: Very empathic yet catchy explanation :) Thank you Daniel!

Comment: So if all fields in Scala are private with implicit getters and setters, how can I make a field _really_ private, means that the field is hidden from outside the class/object?

Comment: @alapeno If you add `private` to it, then you make its getter and setter private. If you add `private[this]`, it will even optimize away the getter and setter and access the field directly, since only one instance will do so.

Answer (score 5):

You can define accessors and mutators like this:

```
class Address(private var _street: String, private var _city: String, private var _postCode: String){
  def street = _street
  def street_=(street: String) = _street = street

  def city = _city
  def city_=(city: String) = _city = city

  def postCode = _postCode
  def postCode_=(postCode: String) = _postCode = postCode
}
```

The need to rename the fields (which might clash with named parameters) and that the constructor ignores the mutator when instantiating the class is a known problem, but no efforts are currently made to improve the situation.

Comment: Thanks. But that seems quite a hassle to go through in scala when we have private fields in the constructor. Would it be not better if we just define standard getter and setter for the field and then do something like  address.setStreet("chnaged") ?

Comment: `street` and `street_=` _are_ standard getter and setter names in Scala. Google for "Uniform access principle".

Comment: @amc The syntax for defining a private field with public getters and setters is `class Address(var street: String)`.

Comment: @amc If you really need a `set*` and `get*` pair, then attach an annotation to the field you want the classic Java getters and setters for: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/reflect/BeanProperty.html